# ARI Authentication (asterisk)

Tags: linux, websocket, asterisk, agi

I can't authenticate in ARI from console browser (lynx, elinks)

cat /etc/asterisk/ari.conf :

```
[general]
enabled = yes       
pretty = yes    
allowed_origins = * 

[sa]
type = user        
read_only = no     
password = test 
password_format = plain
```

cat /etc/asterisk/httpd.conf

```
[general]
servername=Asterisk
enabled=yes
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
bindport=8088`
```

and authentication fails when I enter :

elinks http://localhost:8088/ari/api-docs/resources.json
username : sa passwd : test

I also trying to allow connection from my PC : 
ssh myRealAsteriskIP -L8001:127.0.0.1:8088

but after that I can't connect even to site

Please help me. Thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake I replaced bindaddr=0.0.0.0 to bindaddr=127.0.0.1 and it worked))